# basic linux kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

Is there some basic kernel modules in linux in every version?For example, does every version of linux load parport module.

I want to search some module name in the memory, and get the location of the module.

Answer (score 2):

> > Is there some basic kernel modules in linux in every version?

No, there isn't some kernel module that is present in every version. It is still possible (and, for some environments, preferred) to disable kernel module support altogether.

> > I want to search some module name in the memory, and get the location of the module.

Check for the existence of `/proc/modules`. If it exists, parse it. Each module is listed there. The first field of each line is the name of a module. The sixth field is its address.

Answer (score 0):

For getting all the modules in the running kernel you can use the `lsmod` command.

For searching a specific module you can grep it as...

```
lsmod | grep "your_module_without_inverted_comma"
```

It will give some info as size used by module.

For getting memory location of the module use

```
cat /proc/modules | grep "your_module_without_inverted_comma"
```